# Filtrando um data.frame com base em múltiplas variáveis

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Tenho um data.frame com 9 variáveis de X1 até X9. Os valores dessas variáveis são double. Preciso filtrar as linhas deste data.frame que contenham `(Xi,Xj,Xk) == (5.2,6.3,7.1)` por exemplo.

Consegui solucionar individualmente com o código abaixo. Mas não consegui escrever algo que me possibilitasse executar essa tarefa alterando apenas os valores procurados. Como esses valores podem ocorrer em qualquer combinação das variáveis de X1 a X9 ficou muito complicado.

```
vars <- c("X1","X5","X9")
cond <- c(5.2,6.3,7.1)
lfbase %>%
  filter(
    .data[[vars[[1]]]] == cond[[1]],
    .data[[vars[[2]]]] == cond[[2]],
    .data[[vars[[3]]]] == cond[[3]]
  )
```

Comment: O exemplo não é reprodutível. Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(lfbase)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(lfbase, 20))`? E em que formato estão os valores procurados? Numa lista, num data.frame? Em cada linha as variáveis de `X1` a `X9` devem ter os três valores ou só alguns chega?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após o esclarecimento da pergunta nos comentários:

> Preciso filtrar as linhas onde essas medidas ocorrem em conjunto em qualquer das variáveis X1....X9

A solução continua sendo baseada no comando `filter_at` do `dplyr` com o argumento `any_vars()`. Mas ao invés do operador `|` `OR`, você aplica os filtros sequencialmente:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- lfbase %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("X")), any_vars(. == 5.2)) %>%
                  filter_at(vars(starts_with("X")), any_vars(. == 6.3)) %>% 
                  filter_at(vars(starts_with("X")), any_vars(. == 7.1))
```

Pela sua pergunta, parece que essas são todas as variáveis do seu dataframe ("Tenho um data.frame com 9 variáveis de X1 até X9"). Se esse for o caso, você pode simplificar o código acima com o `filter_all`:

```
df1 <- lfbase %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 5.2))
              %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 6.3))
              %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 7.1))
```

Caso fosse desejado filtrar quaisquer linhas que contivessem quaisquer dos valores mencionados, poderia ser utilizado:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- lfbase %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("X")), any_vars(. == 5.2 | . == 6.3 | . == 7.1))
```

ou

```
df1 <- lfbase %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == 5.2 | . == 6.3 | . == 7.1))
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas contribuições. As soluções funcionaram para a condição "OU", ou seja, utilizando o "|". Quando troco por "&" não retorna nada....<0 linhas> (ou row.names de comprimento 0). O "OU" nãoi resolve meu problema. Preciso filtrar as linhas onde essas medidas ocorrem em conjunto, ou seja, encontrar as linhas onde essas medidas ocorrem em conjunto em qualquer das variáveis X1....X9.

Comment: Ok, editei a resposta para solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: obrigado Socrates. Vou tentar.

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado. Funcionou.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, por favor, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta